# set comma separated number in phpexcel with number_format() function in PHP

Tags: php, yii2, phpexcel

I am generating Excel using PHPExcel.

All code working fine. But comma separated number with `number_format()` function is not working properly.

When i use below code it is working properly.

```
$val=round($data);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('J'.$rowCount,$val);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J'.$rowCount)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode("#,##0");
```

But when i use

```
$val=number_format($data);
```

I am not getting proper output. In excel ,cell value is proper (6,000) but input line it displayed

> '6,000

So can't do autosum.

I don't want to use `round()` function, because i am generating pdf ,csv also and i have common function to get values.

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't need to use round() or number_format() at all.... $val must be a number (int or float or a value that PHP can interpret as numeric), not a value already formatted in any way, no commas, no quotes

Comment: @MarkBaker , Hi mark expecting you :) , yah your are right. but i have common function for  return value to pdf,excel and csv files, and i also need comma , so that i used number_format().

Comment: @MarkBaker , you r right if i not use number_format() , it is proper in excel , but what about pdf and csv ?

Comment: You need to ensure that the value set in the cell isn't already formatted in any way; and the CSV and PDF Writers should use the format mask defined for the cell

Comment: ok, so we can not format it again.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do; if your value is formatted already as a string containing a comma (e.g. `6,000`), then PHP won't treat it as a number but a string... you need to remove the comma for PHP to treat it correctly as a number again

Comment: And if you're using comma as a decimal separator, then you need to replace it with a decimal point `.`.... as is standard in PHP for a number